# Using mocks to check that every object was analysed during iteration

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have no idea how to use mocks to check whether my method was invoked every time it was supposed to. I really don't know how to describe this problem, so I'll go ahead and just show my code:

I have two interacting classes: `Filter` and `Filtrable` (an interface). `Filter` class is able to filter filtrables - which returns filtrables (so it is possible to apply other filters if necessary). Filtering method is just iterating through every filtrable line and checking if that line is filtered - then adding to result filtrable if it is. I wanted to test that every input line is really checked.

Here's the code from `Filter` class:

```
public Filtrable filter(Filtrable input) {
    Filtrable result = input.createEmptyFiltrable();
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        Line line = input.nextLine();
        if(isLineFiltered(line)){
            result.addLine(line);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here's my (failed) attempt to test it:

```
@Test
public void testFilter(){
    Filtrable mockedFiltrable = mock(Filtrable.class);
    when(mockedFiltrable.createEmptyFiltrable()).thenReturn(new StringArrayFiltrable());
    when(mockedFiltrable.hasNextLine()).thenReturn(true,true,true,false);
    when(mockedFiltrable.nextLine()).thenReturn(dummyLine);
    Filter mockedFilter = mock(Filter.class);
    mockedFilter.filter(mockedFiltrable);        
    verify(mockedFilter, times(3)).isLineFiltered(dummyLine);
}
```

The idea here was to make a stubbed filtrable, which consists of three identical dummy lines. Then pass those to a Filter class and check whether method `isLineFiltered` was called exactly three times with the same dummyLine every time.

After reading [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) by Martin Fowler I understand this is completely wrong as I don't test the actual system (`Filter`) anywhere!

So how can I verify if the method in "System Under Test" was invoked three times using mocks? This is crucial, as I'm trying to learn this methodology. I could easily make a test class that inherits from Filter and counts how many times `isLineFiltered` was invoked and then check it. I just feel that this can be done very nicely with mocks.

I'm using Mockito here and it would be nice if any suggestion would use it also (but any other java mocking framework will do of course).

P.S.

After I run the test an exception from Mockito `Wanted but not invoked: filter.isLineFiltered` is thrown.

**EDIT:**

Filtrable interface is as follows:

```
public interface Filtrable {
  public Filtrable createEmptyFiltrable();
  public boolean hasNextLine();
  public void addLine(Line line);
  public Line nextLine() throws FiltrableException;
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Here's how I've done it eventually:

```
@Test
public void testFilter(){
    Filtrable mockedFiltrable = mock(Filtrable.class);
    Filtrable mockedFiltrableResult = mock(Filtrable.class);
    when(mockedFiltrable.createEmptyFiltrable()).thenReturn(mockedFiltrableResult);
    Iterator<Line> mockedIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
    when(mockedFiltrable.iterator()).thenReturn(mockedIterator);
    when(mockedIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true,true,true,false);
    when(mockedIterator.next()).thenReturn(dummyLine);
    Filter filterUnderTest = new TestFilter(true);
    filterUnderTest.filter(mockedFiltrable);        
    verify(mockedFiltrableResult,times(3)).addLine(dummyLine);
}
```

I've changed Filtrable interface to extend Iterable so that's why final solution differs a little from my initial try.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you include the interface definition as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues with your test is that you're not actually testing your filter class since you're also mocked that.

The error is also to be expected.
You specify that `isLineFiltered` is to be invoked three times, but you also mock the class under test. This causes the filter method to also be mocked, thus your `isLineFilter` method isn't being called.

A simple example of how to test using mocks:

```
@Controller
public class KajmanController {
    @Autowired
    private KajmanInfoService kajmanInfoService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getInfo(@RequestParam(value="myParam[]") String[] myParams){
        //some logic
        for (String param : myParams) {
            Info info = kajmanInfoService.getInfo(param);
            //some logic
        }
        //some logic
    }
}
```

Then the only thing you need to mock is the kajmanInfoService.

So your test could look something along the lines of:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class KajmanControllerTest {

        @Mock
        private KajmanInfoService kajmanInfoService ;

        @InjectMocks
        private KajmanController controller;

        @Test
        public void customerInfoRetrieved() {
            //some logic
            when(kajmanInfoService.getInfo(anyString()).thenReturn(expectedInfo);
            //some logic
            String[] expectedInfoArguments = {"A1","B1","C1"};
            controller.getInfo(expectedInfoArguments);
            verify(kajmanInfoService, times(3)).getInfo(anyString);
        }
    }
```

I did do this off the top of my head so it might contain some small mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is there a real need to use Autowired, Controller and RequestMapping annotations? I don't know them and I see they're from Spring MVC? Never used it. Basically you've made a refactoring to move my isLineFiltered (your getInfo) method to another class - is this really necessary? In my use case both methods should be in filter class, there's no better place for them in my opinion.

Comment: There is no need to use those annotations, nor to move your isLineFiltered code. The above is just a quick example of how to test using mocks and has no correlation to your code. The thing you need to note is that I make an actual instance of my controller (in your case the filter class) and that I put the mock in there.

Comment: But since both my methods (filter and isLineFiltered) belong to Filter class - could I use verify on real Filter class instance? I'm afraid it is not possible, or am I wrong? In your code you verify on mocked instance, I would have to verify on real instance since both methods belong to it.

Comment: Can't think of a way of the top of my head, I guess you could verify your addLines.

Comment: Thanks to you I've figured it out.